# KinteticJS - destroying nodes, infinite while loop because child doesn't get removed

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs, destroy

KinerticJS version: 4.4.3

I have this problem when i want to remove a layer from stage. When I call Layer.destroy() kinetic runs upon an node which can't be removed. I don't get any error, but the while loop gets infinite since the loop is based on the length of the children.

```
destroy: function (_nameSpace) {
    var parent = this.getParent(),
    stage = this.getStage(),
    dd = Kinetic.DD,
    go = Kinetic.Global;

    var tempLength
    // destroy children
    while (this.children && this.children.length > 0) {     
        this.children[0].destroy();
    }
}
```

The object which, in my case, can not be removed is a Kinetic.Image. When I trace the node type it returns a Shape (which is correct). Also, i can trace all the stuff which i want to know from the object...

Rectangles do get removed.

I created a low level test in fiddle, and there everything is working fine and dandy, so it has te be something with my code. Than again, the node whicht is not being removed IS a valid object, so why does is not being removed?

I created a error message, so i wouldn't crash my browser everytime:

```
tempLength = this.children.length
this.children[0].destroy();

if (tempLength == this.children.length) {
    throw 'item not removed ' + this.children[0].getNodeType();
}
```

As you can see i check right after i destroyed an item if the length of the children did change, so i can assume thah no other code is interfering. For example adding an node when destroying one.

I'm at a dead end here. I hope somebody can help me out or point me in any direction. Anyway, thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i figured out what the issue was. Somehow i aadded a same Kinetic.Image twice to a layer. When destroying the layer it could not remove it's child.

I assume this is an Kinetic bug. I should not be able to break the framework so (relatively) easy.

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/434